# ¿Por que mi workflow de GitHub Actions me borra el archivo .env?

Tags: github-actions

Buen día, tengo unos problemas con la implementación que hice de GitHub Actions, cree un workflow para hacer CI en mi servidor de AWS lo cual funciona correctamente, sin embargo, como buena practica no tengo un archivo .env en mi repositorio y lo que hago es crear uno en la ruta de mi repositorio en el servidor pero cuando hay una nueva CI este es eliminado y no entiendo.

¿De que modo puedo evitar que se elimine mi archivo .env? o ¿De Que manera puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Mira a ver si tienes un .gitignore que tenga el .env

Comment: Lo tengo en mi repo, y cuando localmente mando cambios a mi rama este no se sube, por ende, voy al servidor donde tengo hospedado el repo y lo creo pero cuando vuelvo a trabajar en mi rama y hago push gihtub actions me despliega en mi servidor gracias a un workflow pero este me elimina el archivo .env.